# Obtain common values between 5 from the same column of different dataframes

Tags: r

I am struggling to extract the common values between a specific column of 5 different dataframes. I know how to do this with two, but not with more.

```
df1$ID<-c(121, 122, 176)
df2$ID<-c(121, 88, 199)
df3$ID<-c(77, 121, 230)
df4$ID<-c(6, 88, 121)
df5$ID<-c(121, 122, 123)
```

In this example, my desired output would be:

```
result<-c(121)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get all the datasets in a `list` and then use `intersect`

```
Reduce(intersect, lapply(mget(paste0('df', 1:5)), `[[`, 'ID'))
#[1] 121
```

---

Or using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
mget(paste0('df', 1:5)) %>%
    map(~ .x %>%
              pull(ID)) %>%
    reduce(intersect)
#[1] 121
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(121, 122, 176))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(121, 88, 199))
df3 <- data.frame(ID = c(77, 121, 230))
df4 <- data.frame(ID = c(6, 88, 121))
df5 <- data.frame(ID = c(121, 122, 123))
```

Comment: Is there any way to select the column by index instead of colname?

Comment: @Jeni Yes, you can just do `pull(1)` if ID is the first column